# SQL Concatenate ids into a specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following query which works great, it puts all my ids in a comma separated list.

```
DECLARE @tmp nvarchar(max)
SET @tmp = ''
        SELECT  @tmp = @tmp + cast(id as nvarchar(max)) + ', ' 
        FROM    dbo.property
```

I want to put my ids in alphabetical order but when I add order by p.Name it only gives my the top one result.

How can I adapt my query to accomplish this?

Comment: . . I added the sql-server tag because you seem to be using SQL Server syntax.

Comment: see this link may help you http://www.innovativephp.com/concatenate-rows-sql-group-concat-function/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really doesn't work?

```
DECLARE @tmp nvarchar(max);
SET @tmp = '';
SELECT  @tmp = @tmp + cast(id as nvarchar(max)) + ', ' 
FROM    dbo.property p
order by p.name;
```

In any case, you can use this method:

```
select @tmp = stuff((select ', ', cast(id as nvarchar(max))
                     from db.property p
                     order by p.name
                     for xml path ('')
                    ), 1, 2, '');
```

Comment: My original query had a where clause which I removed to simplify my question. Without the where clause it works fine

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

```
    SELECT  (cast(ID as nvarchar(max)) + ', ')  AS [text()]
      FROM    dbo.property
  ORDER BY ID
    FOR XML PATH ('')
```